# r- sample unbalanced clearer code

Tags: r, sample

My data (todo5) has a binary class with only 16% of 1. I'm trying to create a balanced set for training a model while keeping the test set unbalanced. Since I have very few records (15K), I can`t loose any 1.
I wrote a code that works but still I found it unclear:
First I create indexes for test:

```
test.idx<-sample((1:nrow(todo5)),nrow(todo5)*.4 )
```

then I create the balanced training set. I remain with all 1 not in test.idx:

```
down.sample<-c((1:nrow(todo5))[todo5$flag_compro==1][-test.idx])
```

I add the same quantity of 0:

```
down.sample<-c(down.sample, sample((1:nrow(todo5))[todo5$flag_compro==0][-test.idx], length(down.sample)))
```

Is there a better (clearer)  way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this approach more clear?

```
todo5 <- data.frame(x=sample(0:1, size=15e3, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.84, 0.16)), y=runif(15e3))
trues <- seq(nrow(todo5))[todo5$x == 1]
falses <- seq(nrow(todo5))[todo5$x != 1]
falses <- sample(falses, size=length(trues))
both <- sort(c(trues, falses))
todo5subset <- todo5[both, ]
summary(todo5)
summary(todo5subset)
```

I wouldn't call this balanced, though. I would use either Mahalanobis distance or matching to achieve balance along other covariates.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain a bit more your suggestion? Or leave a link?

Comment: @GabyP - I think this paper should explain everything and solutions. http://www.jstatsoft.org/v42/i07/paper ... but I think I need to know the economics of the problem to say more.

Answer (score 0):

Construction of a logical vector is reasonably clear:

```
   down.sampleTF <- todo5$flag_compro %in% c(0,1) | rownames(todo) %in% test.idx
   samp.todo <- todo[ down.sampleTF , ]
```